# Android (x,y) continuous touch (drag) coordinates

Tags: android, touch, coordinates

I'm new to android, and I've been trying for a while to find out how can I retrieve the coordinates of a continuous touch on the screen.  for example have 2 vars (x,y) that update in real time as finger moves around. I got it how to find it when the touch is made, but I really don;t get it how to make it return the result after that , when the finger is moving.

I've been trying switch statements, while/for loops in different combination with ACTION_MOVE./ UP/ DOWN .. .still nothing.

I've found like the same question on the website, but the answers only fit for the first step(showing the coordination from the touch only)
I'd really appreciate a solution to this! Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without seeing your code I'm just guessing, but essentially if you don't return `true` to the first call to `onTouchEvent`, you won't see any of the subsequent events in the gesture (MOVE, UP, etc).

Maybe that is your problem? Otherwise please put code sample up.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. That really makes sense(silly mistake). It's working now. Here is also some code for the ones that will encounter the same mistake again:)

Answer (score 10):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final TextView xCoord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    final TextView yCoord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    final View touchView = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    touchView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            final int action = event.getAction();
            switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                    xCoord.setText(String.valueOf((int) event.getX()));
                    yCoord.setText(String.valueOf((int) event.getY()));
                    break;
                }

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:{
                    xCoord.setText(String.valueOf((int) event.getX()));
                    yCoord.setText(String.valueOf((int) event.getY()));
                    break;
                }
            }
            return true;

        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement an `OnTouchListener` for whatever view you want to recognize the drag.

Then in the `OnTouchListener` you need to display the X and Y coordinates. I believe you can get those via `MotionEvent.getRawX()` and `MotionEvent.getRawY()`

You can use the `MotionEvent.getAction()` method to find out when a drag is occurring. I believe the constant is `MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`. Here is some psuedo-code:

Add OnTouchListener interface

```
public class XYZ extends Activity implements OnTouchListener
```

Register the listener in the onCreate method

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    //other code

    View onTouchView = findViewById(R.id.whatever_id);
    onTouchView.setOnTouchListener(this);
}
```

Implement the onTouch method

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) 
{
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE)
    {
        float x = event.getRawX();
        float y = event.getRawY();
        //  Code to display x and y go here
        // you can print the x and y coordinate in a textView for exemple
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot:) While this is right, the problem I was facing was the return statement that was false and so Action_Move had no change to return something.!