# Motion event 'MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE' not registered on touch

Tags: android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

I'm trying to create a dragable view and to change drop target view's alpha depending on distance from dragged view to drop target view. For this I need a way to continually check current position of dragged view. I was trying to implement it using `OnTouchListener`.

Code in `MainActivity's` method `onCreate`:

```
myTextView.setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
```

Code for class `MyTouchListener`:

```
class MyTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {

        Log.i("i", "Touched");

        switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
                ClipData clipData = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");

                View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);

                view.startDrag(clipData, shadowBuilder, view, 0);

                view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                break;
            }

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
                Log.i("i", "this one is never called");
                break;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

After I start dragging my textView, log outputs "Touched" two times and nothing else. Can anybody tell me why case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE is never called?
If this is not the way to implement what I'm trying to do, could you guide me to more proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with

> view.startDrag(clipData, shadowBuilder, view, 0);

If you comment this line out then ACTION_MOVE events will work as they should. In my opinion this ***startDrag*** method somehow eliminates any listening to the original ***view***. While dragging it gives a signal to every other visible view on the screen that there is an object being dragged so other objects could listen to dragging events and nothing else besides that.

UPDATE:
I've actually just found the same question with closely the same answer here:
[onTouch() ACTION_MOVE case is not called while dragging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28166507/ontouch-action-move-case-is-not-called-while-dragging)